# How to create and populate dataframe columns and rows in pandas based on column headers and contents?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and pandas. I'm working with a dataframe where the data looks like this:

| Location | Jan-22 | Feb-22 | Mar-22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 5 | 6 |

And I'm trying to convert the headers into values within a new column and then create a new row with the cell value. For example I'd like it to look like this:

| Location | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Jan-22 |
| A | 2 | Feb-22 |
| A | 3 | Mar-22 |
| B | 4 | Jan-22 |
| B | 5 | Feb-22 |
| B | 6 | Mar-22 |

Any help would be appreciated. I'm still stuck on trying to generate a new column with values based on other column headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pd.DataFrame.melt`:

```
df.melt('Location', var_name='Date', value_name='Value')
```

Output:

```
  Location    Date  Value
0        A  Jan-22      1
1        B  Jan-22      4
2        A  Feb-22      2
3        B  Feb-22      5
4        A  Mar-22      3
5        B  Mar-22      6
```